# Spack failed to install

Tags: macos, installation, spack

I am very new to this. I am trying to install PISM on my computer using spack.

I get the following error:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-143:~ samchester$ spack install pism ^petsc~metis~hdf5~hypre~superlu-dist
==> Bootstrapping clingo from pre-built binaries
==> Bootstrapping clingo from pre-built binaries
==> Bootstrapping clingo from sources
[+] /opt/local (external cmake-3.23.5-riwdvuounbgskxtvk3zvrdi4zlcrew3z)
==> Installing re2c-2.2-5r7oh4myb3qbamndzvesvnkjx52vv3dv
==> No binary for re2c-2.2-5r7oh4myb3qbamndzvesvnkjx52vv3dv found: installing from source
==> Error: FetchError: All fetchers failed for spack-stage-re2c-2.2-5r7oh4myb3qbamndzvesvnkjx52vv3dv

/Users/samchester/spack/lib/spack/spack/package_base.py:1455, in do_fetch:
       1452
       1453        self.stage.create()
       1454        err_msg = None if not self.manual_download else self.download_instr
  >>   1455        start_time = time.time()
       1456        self.stage.fetch(mirror_only, err_msg=err_msg)
       1457        self._fetch_time = time.time() - start_time
       1458


==> Warning: Skipping build of clingo-bootstrap-spack-llpnrd4k7qc4s7eiqotk26iailqtmxzb since re2c-2.2-5r7oh4myb3qbamndzvesvnkjx52vv3dv failed
==> Error: cannot bootstrap the "clingo" Python module from spec "clingo-bootstrap@spack+python %apple-clang target=x86_64" due to the following failures:
github-actions-v0.4 raised RuntimeError: The binary index is empty
github-actions-v0.3 raised RuntimeError: The binary index is empty
spack-install raised InstallError: Terminating after first install failure: FetchError: All fetchers failed for spack-stage-re2c-2.2-5r7oh4myb3qbamndzvesvnkjx52vv3dv
Run `spack --debug ...` for more detailed errors
```

This happens for anything I try to install with spack.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically because spack is failing to clone the repo. Some issues that have caused this in the past for me are not having proxy settings setup on the machine and/or having a really old version of Git.

In this particular instance spack is failing to [bootstrap the concretizer](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping), clingo, which it needs to solve the dependency graph for your software.  The same proxy issues might be the root cause. Bootstrapping starts with trying to pull binaries from a trusted spack mirror, and will fall back to building from source if that fails.